# text export is expanding part of a path - how to suppress this?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've got an orgmode document that describes a system configuration for system admin work.  Part of it has a table that includes a path.

In our shop there are tiers for dev/test/pre-prod/prod and the practice is to maintain parallel paths with the tier names embedded.  So the paths for dev and production might look like this:

```
\\\fred\documents\dev\ssis_files\...

\\\fred\documents\prod\ssis_files\...
```

When I use the text exporter, it expands the third node `\prod` to `[product]`.

How can I suppress this?  I have not found anything in the doc or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This could be abbrev-mode. While in the buffer, try

```
M-x list-abbrevs
```

and see if there is an abbrev for 'prod'. If there is, you can either edit the appropriate abbrev table and remove the entry or turn off abbrev-mode. See the emacs manual under 'Abbrevs' for more details.

Comment: I think this has to do with org identifying it as a latex fragment.  If you debug `org-ascii-latex-fragment` and export the buffer you see the snippet "\prod" is interpreted as latex with an asci value of "[product]"

Comment: In that case, what about wrapping the value in '~'  or '='? e.g. =\\\fred\documents\prod\ssis_files\...=

Comment: I can confirm both those disable the latex expansion, but result in `\`...'` output.  I'm surprised there is no option to shutoff latex symbol interpretation.  I had though maybe `tex:nil`, but then nothing gets exported